# Use javascript to remove all paratheses and content inside

Tags: jquery, regex

I am parsing an XML feed on my site, and one of the feeds shows up in the following format:  **Title of News Story (January 15th, 2013)**. I would like to remove the parenthesis and all content inside of it.

I stored the entire string in a variable like so:  `var title = $(this).text();`

I then use jquery's each to loop through every RSS title like so:

```
$('h4 a').each(function() {

      var title = $(this).text();

});
```

I can then use regex to grab the content inside the parenthesis and alert it like so:

```
var title = $(this).text();
var regex = new RegExp('\\((.*?)\\)', 'g');
var match, matches = [];
while(match = regex.exec(title))
    matches.push(match[1]);
alert(matches);
```

This is fine, but how would I delete these form the string?

Comment: So what have you tried in order to remove this content?

Comment: I am not familiar with RegEx, so I have not tried using it, yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a base, and refine your regular expression as you need for the date.

```
$('h4 a').each(function() {
    var new_text = $(this).text().replace(/((\s*)\((.*)\))/, "");
    $(this).text(new_text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that titles will follow the same pattern, you don't need to use regular expressions to accomplish this:

```
function removeDate(title) {
    var index = title.lastIndexOf('(');
    return title.substr(0, index).trim();
}

$('h4 a').each(function() {
    $(this).text(removeDate($(this).text());
});
```